# Wrong output when printing one of the elements in argv

Tags: c, arguments

I am writing a program that recurses through directories but came across a strange problem with my code. I compile and run the code with the following:

```
./sorter -c food -d thisdir -o thatdir
```

The following gives me a total argument count of 7. However when I try to check my inputs, I get unexpected results:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int checkInputs = checkFlags(argc,argv);
  if(checkInputs == 1){
    fileSearch("."); 
  }
  else if(checkInputs == 2){
    printf("arg counts %d\n",argc); 
    printf("%s\n",argv[4]);
    fileSearch(argv[4]);
  }
  else if(checkInputs == 3){
    printf("arg counts %d\n",argc); 
    printf("%s\n",argv[4]);
    fileSearch(argv[4]); 
  }

  return 0;  
}
```

It returns the expected output when checkInputs is 2 but when it is 3 I get the following when I print argv[4]:

```
-d
```

The following is my checkInputs function, which may be causing this:

```
int checkFlags(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  int output;

  if(argc < 3){
    printf("Not enough arguments\n");
    output = 0;
    return output;
  }
  else{
    int options;
    char * input = NULL;

    while((options = getopt(argc,argv,"c:d::o::")) != -1){
      switch(options) {
      case 'c':
        input = optarg;
        //printf("Mandatory flag: %s\n",optarg);
        output = 1;
        break;

      case 'd':
        //printf("We have an optional %s\n",argv[4]);
        output = 2;
        break;

      case 'o':
        //printf("We have two optionals: -d: %s & -o: %s\n",argv[4],argv[6]);
        output = 3;
        break;

      /* Probably don't need this case statement*/
      case '?':
        if(optopt == 'c'){
          printf("Unknown option, -%c not present\n",optopt);
          exit(0);
        }
          break;
        }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

Everything works fine however if the program is only compiled with the first 2 flags.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Sorry, whenever I print out argv[4] it gives me the incorrect output whenever I print it when checkInputs equals 3.

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] in your question? (Please read the linked article.)

Comment: I don't believe you are correctly reading the getopt documentation. There is no such thing as a mandatory flag. There are optional flags which don't take an argument; optional flags which do take an argument; and -- as a Gnu extension -- optional flags with an optional argument. These last ones should usually be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

By debugging your code, I actually get a segmentation fault, when `checkInputs == 2` and `./program -c hello -d`. You should fix this, by adding a IF and check if a path is provided, for the option `-d`. Also keep in mind, that the sequence of the parameters can differ. You can save the extra options in a variable to access them out of the checkFlags function.

Executing `./program -c food -d thisdir -o thatdir` outputs:

```
Mandatory flag: food
We have an optional thisdir
We have two optionals: -d: thisdir & -o: thatdir
arg counts 7
-o
```

It prints the expected.